# Photon temperature above Electroweak Symmetry Breaking (EWSB) transition

Tags: cosmology, temperature, symmetry-breaking, higgs

In discussions of the history of our Universe, photon temperature is substituted for time. As the Universe cools, phase transitions break symmetries, including electroweak symmetry.

Why does it make sense to speak of photon temperature prior to Electroweak Symmetry Breaking (EWSB)? Is this a misnomer? Is it shorthand for "boson for unbroken $U(1)$" temperature? Or did I misunderstand something.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for putting a modifier such as "photon" before "temperature." If there's thermal equilibrium, there is only one temperature.

Comment: Ah, so maybe this partially answers my question. Maybe photon temperature is used only in cases in which a particle species decouples from thermal equilibrium. But that can still happen above the scale of EWSB for thermal relics like dark matter.

Comment: Another example is that gravitational waves are not now and never have been in thermal equilibrium with the matter degrees of freedom.